# How much heat (in J) is required to produce 2.0L of N2(g) at 77.36 K and 1.0 atm?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

The only thing that is given is:

**The enthalpy of vaporization for $N_2(l)$ is 5.56 kJ/mol.**

There aren't any examples similar to this problem in the textbook. I only know how to get energy using:

$q=mcΔT$ and $w=PΔV$

No clue what to do with the enthalpy of vaporization value.

**UPDATE**: Solved it by first getting number of moles ($n$) via $PV=nRT$ then multiplying moles by 5.56 kJ/mol. Moles cancel out, leaving only kJ, 1.75kJ to be precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nitrogen's boiling point is 77.36 K , it appears that the question is asking how much heat is required to boil nitrogen to produce 2.0 L at 1 atm.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't help much

Comment: Using the ideal gas law, how many moles of nitrogen are in 2.0 L at 1 atm and 77.36 K? Then find the amount of heat needed to convert that amount from liquid to gas.

Comment: Once i get the # of moles, which formula do i need to apply to get heat?

Comment: @TwilightPonyInc. You should have used the equation. A favorite problem involves heating ice to the freezing point, melting the ice, and then heating the water to a defined temperature. When you melt the ice, that is the equation you want.